# Forcing a table rehash not working after a previous rehash

Tags: lua, garbage-collection

I've created a function that resizes an array and sets new entries to 0, but can also decrease the size of the array in 2 different ways:
1. Simply setting the `n` property to the new size (the length operator cannot be used because of this reason).
2. Setting all values after the new size to nil up to 2*size to force a rehash.

```
local function resize(array, elements, free)
    local size = array.n

    if elements < size then     -- Decrease Size
        array.n = elements
        if free then
            size = math.max(size, #array)   -- In case of multiple resizes
            local base = elements + 1
            for idx = base, 2*size do       -- Force a rehash -> free extra unneeded memory
                array[idx] = nil
            end
        end
    elseif elements > size then -- Increase Size
        array.n = elements
        for idx = size + 1, elements do
            array[idx] = 0
        end
    end
end
```

How I tested it:

```
local mem = {n=0};
resize(mem, 50000)
print(mem.n, #mem)              -- 50000 50000
print(collectgarbage("count"))  -- relatively large number

resize(mem, 10000, true)
print(mem.n, #mem)              -- 10000 10000
print(collectgarbage("count"))  -- smaller number

resize(mem, 20, true)
print(mem.n, #mem)              -- 20 20
print(collectgarbage("count"))  -- same number as above, but it should be a smaller number
```

However when I don't pass `true` as the third argument to the second call of resize (so it doesn't force a rehash on the second call), the third call does end up rehashing it.

Am I missing something? I'm expecting the third one to also rehash after the second one has.

Comment: Your question is very confusing. The second argument of resize is the number of elements, You mean third argument. the third call does something when the second does not but you expect the third to doe something after the second has? what?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was referring to the third argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a clearer picture of how the table usually looks like before and after the resizes:

```
table: 0x15bd3d0    n:  0       #:  0       narr:   0       nrec:   1
table: 0x15bd3d0    n:  50000   #:  50000   narr:   65536   nrec:   1
table: 0x15bd3d0    n:  10000   #:  10000   narr:   16384   nrec:   2
table: 0x15bd3d0    n:  20      #:  20      narr:   16384   nrec:   2
```

And here is what happens:

- During the resize to 50000 elements, the table is rehashed several times, and at the end it contains exactly one hash part slot for the `n` field and enough array part slots for the integer keys.
- During the shrinking to 10000 elements, you first assign `nil` to the integer keys 10001 to 65536, and then from 65537 to 100000. The first group of assignments will *never* cause a rehash, because you assign to existing fields. This has to do with the [guarantees for the `next` function](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-next). The second group of assignments will cause rehashes, but since you are assinging `nil`s, Lua will realize at some point that the array part of the table is more than half empty (see comment at the beginning of [`ltable.c`](http://www.lua.org/source/5.3/ltable.c.html)). Lua will then shrink the array part to a reasonable size and use a second hash slot for the new key. But since you are assigning `nil`s, that second hash slot is never occupied, and Lua is free to re-use it for *all* the remaining assignments (and it often but not always does). You wouldn't notice a rehash at this point anyway, because you will always end up with the 16384 array slots and 2 hash slots (one for `n`, one for the new element to be assigned).
- The shrinking to 20 elements just continues this way, with the exception that a second hash slot is already available. So you might *never* get a rehash (and the array size stays larger than necessary), but if you *do* (Lua for some reason doesn't like the one free hash slot), you'll see the number of array slots drop to a reasonable level.

This is what it looks like when you *do* get a rehash during the second shrinking:

```
table: 0x11c43d0    n:  0       #:  0       narr:   0       nrec:   1
table: 0x11c43d0    n:  50000   #:  50000   narr:   65536   nrec:   1
table: 0x11c43d0    n:  10000   #:  10000   narr:   16384   nrec:   2
table: 0x11c43d0    n:  20      #:  20      narr:   32      nrec:   2
```

If you want to repeat my experiments, the git HEAD version of [`lua-getsize`](https://github.com/siffiejoe/lua-getsize) (original version [here](http://code.matthewwild.co.uk/lua-getsize/)) now also returns the number of slots in the array/hash parts of a table.

Comment: That clears a lot up, it was much more complicated that I thought. Thank you

Comment: So pretty much, there is no way I can _always_ force a rehash the way I'm doing it then?

Comment: @Matthew: I would try the following to force a rehash when shrinking to size `n`: *grow* the array by 100% plus 2 using non-`nil` values. That should force a rehash and set the number of hash part slots to 1 (for the `n` field). Then clear the array elements you don't want using `nil` (no rehash). Then assign a non-`nil` value to a non-integer key. This  forces another rehash and leaves you with an array part size not larger than `2*n` and 2 hash slots. Then clear the hash slot you just assigned to. If don't otherwise allocate hash slots, I *think* that should work.

Comment: Obviously, this is not something you are supposed to do! What do you need it for?

Comment: I don't really need it, it's really just for the "fun" of it. I could easily do without it for what I'm doing.